# Run "docker pull" in container behind proxy

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a container behind proxy. I setup proxy for docker, but if I run pull in container, i have timeout error.
For eximple:
I pull image in container "`sudo docker exec -it *container name* docker pull node:8`", command run with error: "Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)".
But simple "sudo docker pull node:8" run OK.

Setup proxy for docker in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`.

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://10.0.78.200:3128/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.0.78.200:3128/"
```

Setup proxy for container in ENV, check it this way: "**`sudo docker exec -it jetbrainsinfra_teamcity-agent-1_1 sh -c 'env | grep -i  _PROXY`'**" -> HTTPS_PROXY="http://10.0.78.200:3128", HTTP_PROXY="http://10.0.78.200:3128".

What should i do?

I am not good with docker, sorry if it's stupid question ^_________^.

Comment: This isn't really related to the proxy but rather that you're trying to run docker in docker and the least you need is the `--privileged` flag --> https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/